# jna Pointer in 32 bit JRE

Tags: java, winapi, jna, magnification-api

I am using jna to call Magnification api functions in Java.

MagImageScalingCallback.java

```
package jna.extra;

import com.sun.jna.Callback;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HRGN;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.RECT;

public interface MagImageScalingCallback extends Callback{
    public Boolean MagImageScalingCallback(HWND hwnd, Pointer srcdata,MAGIMAGEHEADER srcheader, Pointer destdata,MAGIMAGEHEADER destheader,RECT source,RECT clipped,HRGN dirty);
}
```

MAGIMAGEHEADER.java

```
package jna.extra;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Guid.GUID;


public class MAGIMAGEHEADER extends com.sun.jna.Structure {
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public GUID format;
    public int stride;
    public int offset;
    public int cbsize;

    public List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("width","height","format","stride","offset","cbsize");
    }
}
```

Magnification.java

```
package jna.extra;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.DWORD;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.RECT;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions;


public interface Magnification extends StdCallLibrary {

    Magnification INSTANCE = (Magnification) Native.loadLibrary("magnification", Magnification.class,
                                                W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    public Boolean MagInitialize();

    public boolean MagSetWindowFilterList(HWND hwndMag, DWORD dword, int i,
            HWND[] excludeHWNDs);

    public boolean MagSetWindowSource(HWND hwndMag, RECT sourceRect);

    public void MagGetWindowFilterList(HWND hwndMag, DWORD dword, int i, HWND[] test);

    public boolean MagSetImageScalingCallback(HWND hwndMag,MagImageScalingCallback MagImageScalingCallback);

    public MagImageScalingCallback MagGetImageScalingCallback(HWND hwndMag);

}
```

WinGDIExtra.java

```
package jna.extra;

import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.DWORD;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinGDI;

public interface WinGDIExtra extends WinGDI {

    public DWORD SRCCOPY = new DWORD(0x00CC0020);
    public DWORD SRCPAINT = new DWORD(0x00ee0086);
    public DWORD SRCAND = new DWORD(0x008800c6);
    public DWORD SRCINVERT = new DWORD(0x00660046);
    public DWORD SRCERASE = new DWORD(0x00440328);

    public DWORD NOTSRCCOPY = new DWORD(0x00330008);
    public DWORD NOTSRCERASE = new DWORD(0x001100a6);
    public DWORD MERGECOPY = new DWORD(0x00c000ca);
    public DWORD MERGEPAINT = new DWORD(0x00bb0226);

    public DWORD PATCOPY = new DWORD(0x00f00021);
    public DWORD PATPAINT = new DWORD(0x00fb0a09);
    public DWORD PATINVERT = new DWORD(0x005a0049);
    public DWORD DSTINVERT = new DWORD(0x00550009);
    public DWORD WHITENESS = new DWORD(0x00ff0062);
    public DWORD BLACKNESS = new DWORD(0x00000042);
    public DWORD CAPTUREBLT = new DWORD(0x00CC0020 | 0x40000000);
    public DWORD Black = new DWORD(0x00000000);

    public long WS_CHILD = 0x40000000L;
    public long WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000L;
    public long MS_SHOWMAGNIFIEDCURSOR = 0x0001L; 


    public long WS_EX_TOPMOST = 0x00000008L;
    public long WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x00080000;
    public long WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020L;

    public long WS_CLIPCHILDREN = 0x02000000L;

    public long MW_FILTERMODE_EXCLUDE = 0;

}
```

My code

```
package jna.extra;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.DWORD;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HRGN;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.RECT;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;

import luz.winapi.jna.User32;

public class screenSkip {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        if(!Magnification.INSTANCE.MagInitialize()){
            System.out.println("Cannot Intialize Magnification API");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        RECT desktopRect= new RECT();
        HWND desktop = User32.INSTANCE.GetDesktopWindow();
        if(desktop==null){
            System.out.println("Problem with Desktop");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(!User32Extra.INSTANCE.GetWindowRect(desktop, desktopRect)){
            System.err.println("Cannot get window rect");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        HWND top = User32Extra.INSTANCE.CreateWindowEx(new DWORD(WinGDIExtra.WS_EX_TOPMOST | WinGDIExtra.WS_EX_LAYERED | WinGDIExtra.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT), "#32770", "Parent Window", new DWORD(WinGDIExtra.WS_CLIPCHILDREN), desktopRect.left, desktopRect.top, desktopRect.right-desktopRect.left, desktopRect.bottom-desktopRect.top, desktop, null, null, null);

        if(top==null){
            System.out.println("Problem while creating Parent Window and the error is "+Native.getLastError());
            System.exit(0);
        }

        HWND hwndMag=null;
        System.out.println(Native.getLastError());
        hwndMag = User32Extra.INSTANCE.CreateWindowEx(null, "Magnifier", "MagWindow", new DWORD(WinGDIExtra.WS_CHILD | WinGDIExtra.MS_SHOWMAGNIFIEDCURSOR | WinGDIExtra.WS_VISIBLE), desktopRect.left, desktopRect.top, desktopRect.right-desktopRect.left, desktopRect.bottom-desktopRect.top, top, null, Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle(null), null);
        if(hwndMag==null){
            System.err.println("Problem while creating Magnifier Window and the error is "+Native.getLastError());
            System.exit(0);
        }

        RECT sourceRect= new RECT();

        if(!User32Extra.INSTANCE.GetWindowRect(desktop, sourceRect)){
            System.err.println("Cannot get window rect");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(1366, 768, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        if(!Magnification.INSTANCE.MagSetImageScalingCallback(hwndMag,new MagImageScalingCallback() {

            public Boolean MagImageScalingCallback(HWND hwnd, Pointer srcdata,
                    MAGIMAGEHEADER srcheader, Pointer destdata,
                    MAGIMAGEHEADER destheader, RECT source, RECT clipped, HRGN dirty) {
                image.setRGB(0, 0, srcheader.width, srcheader.height, srcdata.getIntArray(0, srcheader.width * srcheader.height ), 0, srcheader.width);
                return true;
            }
        })){
            System.err.println("Error occured while setting callback");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (!Magnification.INSTANCE.MagSetWindowSource(hwndMag, sourceRect))
        {
            System.err.println("Cannot copy");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, "JPEG", new File("printed1.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!Magnification.INSTANCE.MagSetWindowSource(hwndMag, sourceRect))
        {
            System.err.println("Cannot copy");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

If the `MagSetWindowSource` function is called the `MagImageScalingCallback` function is called.

The problem is if I run this code with jre7(64 bit) everything works fine. But if I run the same code in jre7(32 bit), I am getting the following error.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x10002a21, pid=5552, tid=4884
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_80-b15) (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.80-b11 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jna6797525900717560222.dll+0x2a21]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

Stack: [0x05c60000,0x05cb0000],  sp=0x05cae4d0,  free space=313k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [jna6797525900717560222.dll+0x2a21]
j  com.sun.jna.Pointer._getInt(J)I+0
j  com.sun.jna.Pointer.getInt(J)I+6
j  com.sun.jna.Pointer.getValue(JLjava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+340
j  com.sun.jna.Structure.readField(Lcom/sun/jna/Structure$StructField;)Ljava/lang/Object;+168
j  com.sun.jna.Structure.read()V+82
j  com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.convertArgument(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;+330
j  com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.invokeCallback([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+95
j  com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.callback([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+2
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x1429aa]
V  [jvm.dll+0x20743e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x142a2d]
V  [jvm.dll+0xcb7b2]
V  [jvm.dll+0xcd5df]
C  [jna6797525900717560222.dll+0x9dd2]
C  [jna6797525900717560222.dll+0xa47f]
C  [jna6797525900717560222.dll+0xc864]
C  [jna6797525900717560222.dll+0xcdee]
C  0x00b80012
C  [magnification.dll+0x5434]
C  [magnification.dll+0x5a2c]
C  [magnification.dll+0x5f5d]
C  [magnification.dll+0x612a]
C  [magnification.dll+0x28ab]
C  [USER32.dll+0x162fa]
C  [USER32.dll+0x16d3a]
C  [USER32.dll+0x1965e]
C  [USER32.dll+0x196c5]
C  [magnification.dll+0x22e2]
C  [jna6797525900717560222.dll+0xcc77]
C  [jna6797525900717560222.dll+0xc78a]
C  [jna6797525900717560222.dll+0x4561]
C  [jna6797525900717560222.dll+0x4d2e]
j  com.sun.jna.Function.invokeInt(I[Ljava/lang/Object;)I+0
j  com.sun.jna.Function.invoke([Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;+315
j  com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/lang/Object;+214
j  com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+341
j  com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.MagSetWindowSource(Lcom/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinDef$HWND;Lcom/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinDef$RECT;)Z+20
j  org.redfire.screen.ScreenShare$CaptureScreen.run()V+674
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x1429aa]
V  [jvm.dll+0x20743e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x142b75]
V  [jvm.dll+0x142bd7]
V  [jvm.dll+0xed5cf]
V  [jvm.dll+0x163c4c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1646a7]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1a92f9]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x5c556]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x5c600]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x133aa]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39f72]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39f45]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.sun.jna.Pointer._getInt(J)I+0
j  com.sun.jna.Pointer.getInt(J)I+6
j  com.sun.jna.Pointer.getValue(JLjava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+340
j  com.sun.jna.Structure.readField(Lcom/sun/jna/Structure$StructField;)Ljava/lang/Object;+168
j  com.sun.jna.Structure.read()V+82
j  com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.convertArgument(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;+330
j  com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.invokeCallback([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+95
j  com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.callback([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+2
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  com.sun.jna.Function.invokeInt(I[Ljava/lang/Object;)I+0
j  com.sun.jna.Function.invoke([Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;+315
j  com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/lang/Object;+214
j  com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+341
j  com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.MagSetWindowSource(Lcom/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinDef$HWND;Lcom/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinDef$RECT;)Z+20
j  org.redfire.screen.ScreenShare$CaptureScreen.run()V+674
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

How to solve this issue? How can I make this work on a 32-bit JRE?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure I've said this to you before, but you've only shown part of the code. Why can't you show an MCVE? Then we would not have to guess.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Updated question.

Comment: No. Please do a websearch to understand what MCVE means. Your update is neither minimal nor complete. Can you compile the code in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the [`MagImageScalingCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692392(v=vs.85).aspx) is defined as a `WINAPI` function, which means you have to define the callback as being a child of `StdCallCallback`.

Secondly, the return type is a simple boolean (you should not use Boolean for this).

Thirdly, the parameters of the callback are `MAGIMAGEHEADER`, and not `MAGIMAGEHEADER *`, and the `RECT` is not a `RECT *`, which means they needs to be passed by value; so the callback declaration needs to be changed like so:

I added a `RectByValue` class, containing the following:

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;

public class RectByValue extends WinDef.RECT implements Structure.ByValue {}
```

I changed the `MagImageScalingCallback` class with the following:

```
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public interface MagImageScalingCallback extends StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback {
   public boolean MagImageScalingCallback(HWND hwnd, Pointer srcdata,MAGIMAGEHEADER.ByValue srcheader, Pointer destdata,MAGIMAGEHEADER.ByValue destheader,RectByValue source,RectByValue clipped,HRGN dirty);
}
```

You will need to add `ByValue` support to `MAGIMAGEHEADER`; and also use a `SIZE_T` for the last element of the structure:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Guid.GUID;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.BaseTSD;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;

public class MAGIMAGEHEADER extends Structure {
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public GUID format;
    public int stride;
    public int offset;
    public BaseTSD.SIZE_T cbsize;

    public List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("width","height","format", "stride","offset","cbsize");
    }

    public static class ByValue extends MAGIMAGEHEADER implements Structure.ByValue {
        public ByValue() {}

        public ByValue(MAGIMAGEHEADER magimageheader) {
            super (magimageheader.getPointer());

            width = magimageheader.width;
            height = magimageheader.height;
            format = magimageheader.format;
            stride = magimageheader.stride;
            offset = magimageheader.offset;
            cbsize = magimageheader.cbsize;
        }

        public ByValue(Pointer memory) {
            super(memory);
        }
    }

    public MAGIMAGEHEADER(Pointer memory) {
        super(memory);
        read();
    }

    public MAGIMAGEHEADER() {
    }
}
```

I changed the screen size to match my display on `screenSkip` so it's `new BufferedImage(2160, 1440...` instead of `1366, 786`, and changed the callback code creator to:

```
if(!Magnification.INSTANCE.MagSetImageScalingCallback(hwndMag, new MagImageScalingCallback() {

    public boolean MagImageScalingCallback(HWND hwnd, Pointer srcdata,
            MAGIMAGEHEADER.ByValue srcheader, Pointer destdata,
            MAGIMAGEHEADER.ByValue destheader, RectByValue source, RectByValue clipped, HRGN dirty) {
        image.setRGB(0, 0, srcheader.width, srcheader.height, srcdata.getIntArray(0, srcheader.width * srcheader.height ), 0, srcheader.width);
        return true;
    }
})){
    System.err.println("Error occured while setting callback");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

The end product of running this in 32bit or 64bit mode is a file called 
This is about as minimal as I can think will achieve what you want.

.... huh ... it gives me a blank image on 32bit. That seems incorrect.

Comment: Thanks! I cannot find any `StdCallLibrary.StdCallback` interface. So, I have used `StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback`. But I am getting the same error.

Comment: @Mahesh please add your definition for all the relevant classes (e.g. MAGIMAGEHEADER) as you may have defined them incorrectly.

Comment: @Mahesh there are a few changes needed. I'll explain in the answer

Comment: @Mahesh I have your code, with a minor change for `CreateWindowEx` - I used `User32Util.createWindowEx`, and added a class implementing `GetWindowRect` & `GetDesktopWindow` just to get past those missing classes working, producing the .jpg for java 7 32bit, java 8 32bit & java 8 64bit.

Comment: @Petesh can you add the modifications in the answer.

Comment: @Mahesh it's all pushed to github at: https://github.com/petesh/jna-magnification

Comment: @Petesh The `RECT` parameters are by value too. The header file reads: `typedef BOOL (CALLBACK* MagImageScalingCallback)(HWND hwnd, void * srcdata, MAGIMAGEHEADER srcheader, void * destdata, MAGIMAGEHEADER destheader, RECT unclipped, RECT clipped, HRGN dirty );`

Comment: @Petesh I just want to clarify. Do you get the desktop image if you use java 7 32 bit?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan oops, missed that, even though it worked (slap myself for insufficient checking). I've updated the github repo with the relevant changes and will update the answer

Comment: @Petesh It's a very weird callback prototype. Looks like it was written by somebody with little experience of Win32, and not properly reviewed. All of the structs should be passed by ref by convention.

Comment: @Mahesh I get a blank image on a 32bit JRE, and it invokes the callback twice. The kicker is in the line [Note  The Magnification API is not supported under WOW64; that is, a 32-bit magnifier application will not run correctly on 64-bit Windows.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692162%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: As I've said to you before Mahesh, `MagImageScalingCallback` is deprecated. The documentation states that clearly. I'm surprised that you have ignored this advice.

Comment: @Petesh Even if I run this on a 32 bit windows with 32 bit JRE, I am getting blank screen. What might be the reason for that? is this programatical error or limitation of Magnification API.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `MagImageScalingCallback` is even working well in Windows 10. I don't know the reason why it is working(even though deprecated). As it is working I am using that.