# How do I properly map a `MagImageScalingCallback` using JNA?

Tags: java, pointers, winapi, jna

I am using jna.jar, jna-3.2.5.jar and jna-3.3.0-platform.jar in my Java Project.

This is the Winapi function I want to replicate.

```
BOOL WINAPI MagImageScalingCallback(
  _In_  HWND           hwnd,
  _In_  void           *srcdata,
  _In_  MAGIMAGEHEADER srcheader,
  _Out_ void           *destdata,
  _In_  MAGIMAGEHEADER destheader,
  _In_  RECT           unclipped,
  _In_  RECT           clipped,
  _In_  HRGN           dirty
);
```

This is my Java code

```
public interface MagImageScalingCallback extends StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback{
    public boolean MagImageScalingCallback(HWND hwnd,
            Pointer srcdata,
            MAGIMAGEHEADER.ByValue srcheader,
            Pointer destdata,
            MAGIMAGEHEADER.ByValue destheader,
            RectByValue source,
            RectByValue clipped,
            HRGN dirty);
}
```

When I get into this method of the callback, I get unexpected results:

```
    public boolean MagImageScalingCallback(HWND hwnd, Pointer srcdata,
            MAGIMAGEHEADER.ByValue srcheader, Pointer destdata,
            MAGIMAGEHEADER.ByValue destheader, RectByValue source, RectByValue clipped, HRGN dirty) {
        image.setRGB(0, 0, srcheader.width, srcheader.height, srcdata.getIntArray(0, srcheader.width * srcheader.height ), 0, srcheader.width);
        return true;
    }
```

This table explains What works and what doesn't work in 32 bit and 64 bit system when I change the data type of the variables.

```
+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| Parameter    | Data type    |   64 bit    |   32 bit    |
+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| source       | WinDef.RECT  |   Working   | Not Working |
| clipped      | WinDef.RECT  |   Working   | Not Working |
| source       | RectByValue  |   Working   |   Working   |
| source       | RectByValue  |   Working   |   Working   |
| srcdata      | Pointer      |   Working   | Not Working |
| destdata     | Pointer      |   Working   | Not Working |
+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

> Not working means a totally black image in the result

If I use the above code in a 64 bit system, I can capture the desktop(I can access the data from the Pointer variable). If I use the same code in 32 bit system, I am not getting any image. You can see [my whole code](https://github.com/petesh/jna-magnification)

Why is the error in my code? How can I fix that?

For your Information. As you see in the `screenSkip.java`, Whenever MagSetWindowSource function is called. MagImageScalingCallback(in line 80) is called.

Problems in this [section of code](https://github.com/petesh/jna-magnification/blob/master/screenSkip.java#L80-L85)

If I run this code on a 64 bit system `srcdata` and `destdata` will hold the array of integer pixels of the Desktop(If I save this as image, it captures the desktop). But if I run the same code on 32 bit system these both variable array pixel value is always zero(If I save the image, it is always black)

64 bit system
[image]

32 bit system
[image]

@david-heffernan I am running this code on a 32-bit system. I know `The Magnification API is not supported under WOW64;`. Which means 32-bit magnification application works on a 32-bit system and 64-bit magnification application works on a 64-bit system. Please stop commenting that magnification API doesn't work on WOW64 and try to execute this code on a 32-bit system.

As for your request the below image shows the configuration of my System.

[image]

Comment: What is the `C` idiom you are trying to replicate?  `struct` handling is by reference (`struct *`) for parameters and by value (`struct`) in aggregate fields.  The Java `Structure` tagging interfaces (`ByValue`, `ByReference`) are there to force the complementary convention.  All other values are passed by value and there exists a range of `ByReference` implementations in the `com.sun.jna.ptr` package to facilitate passing "the address of" a value.

Comment: @technomage I have updated the question. Please ping me if you didn't understand.

Comment: `Pointer` is always passed by value.  Whether 64- or 32-bit, if the native signature asks for a struct by value, you need to pass it by value (it's only by chance that passing a `struct*` happened to work in your 64-bit case, due to how the compiler handles passing small `struct` values).

Comment: @technomage how can I fix the issue?

Comment: Please clarify (in your question) what works and what doesn't work, on both 32- and 64-bit versions.  Indicate the expected and actual outcomes.

Comment: @technomage I have updated the question. Hope that is the data you required.

Comment: You definitely need to use `ByValue` variants of all `Structure` types passed in to the callback.  You should also avoid initializing any `ByValue` variant from an existing `Pointer`, or you may get unexpected results.  Please be more descriptive about the problems you're having with [this section of code](https://github.com/petesh/jna-magnification/blob/master/screenSkip.java#L80-L85).

Comment: @technomage Updated the problem

Comment: Have you compared the contents of the [`MAGIMAGEHEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692384(v=vs.85).aspx) (which describes the layout of the data you're receiving) between the 32- and 64-bit versions?  Examine the bytes per row ("stride"), offset, and total size.

Comment: All the values are same for 32 bit and 64 bit system.

Comment: Run the tests on the same system, installing a 32-bit JVM on the 64-bit system if necessary.  You'll get the black desktop if, for instance, the code is running as a service but does not have desktop access enabled.

Comment: @technomage I have tried that too(installing 32-bit JVM), I got the same result(black desktop).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044727/jna-pointer-in-32-bit-jre

Comment: @technomage 'srcdata.SIZE' in 64 bit system is '8' where as in 32 bit system is '4'. Does that affect the data?

Comment: If you're using the `SIZE_T` type JNA should take care of the size difference (assuming you mean the cbSize field in `MAGIMAGEHEADER`).  From the [SO link above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044727/jna-pointer-in-32-bit-jre), I wouldn't expect this to work in 32-bit mode on 64-bit windows.

Comment: Yes, That doesn't work on WOW64 but it should work on 32 bit system. I have tried the cpp code in visual Studio it is working fine on a 32 bit system.

Answer (score 1):

The callback is proper - there is no flaw in your code, besides you are using deprecated functions.

Consider using this:

```java
try {
    Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    BufferedImage  capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
    ImageIO.write(capture, "JPEG", new File("printed1.jpg"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I want some windows to be skipped from capturing. Your answer is a very basic code.

Comment: you can still use some parts of your code to determine the rectangle to grab.